# Social Icon Meaning

Tags: diablo-iii

What does the "1" mean on the following "Social" icon:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure enough to "answer" and can't check right now but I think the 1 is the number of friends that you have added while the 2nd 'friend' is a player you have played with in the past but have not added as a Friend. You just shared a game with them.

Comment: Possibly correct. The "1" is a "2" now.

Comment: Is it the number of online friends playing Diablo 3?

Comment: I'm pretty sure its the number of pending friend invitations, but i'm not able to check this.

Answer (score 3):

It's pending friend invitations.  Or as I normally think of it, the number of spams I've received since I last did a report wave (I get more spam invitations than real ones).  At least, that's the only time that I've seen a number there.